# Write a function that splits a list of integers into sublists?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have no clue where to begin with this, I am new to coding so I am trying my best but I am stuck. I am asking for where to begin or some psuedocode, not for you to write it for me.

Say you have a variable `n` which is a list of integers which you need to split up into a sublist of `x` length.

Next suppose that `k` is `len(n)/len_of_sublist`

The values from numbers at indexes `0, k, 2k, ...` will be placed in the ﬁrst sub-list.

The values from numbers at indexes `1, k + 1, 2k + 1, ...` will be placed in the second sub-list.

The values from numbers at indexes `2, k + 2, 2k + 2, ...` will be placed in the third sub-list.

Comment: Welcome. Why don't you tell us what you do know, and we'll see how we can help. For example, how are you initializing your sublists? Have you tried constructing a loop to solve this problem?

Comment: My problem is i only know absolute basics as this is my first coding class but the professor goes extremely fast and does not explain everything that is assisgned so we are forced to try and teach ourselves which is why im asking for help with this. He never taught it. I tried getting help from other classmates but they seem to be struggling a well

Answer (score 0):

to create list of sublist (`l2`) from original list (`l1`), `i` is the length of sublist :

```
>>> l1 =  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> i=2
>>> l2= [l1[n:n+i] for n in range(0, len(l1), i)]
>>> l2
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
```

With an other c]value of `i` :

```
>>> i=3
>>> l2= [l1[n:n+i] for n in range(0, len(l1), i)]
>>> l2
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> n=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
>>> k=4
>>> zip(*[n[i:i+l] for i in range(0,len(n),l)])
[(1, 5, 9), (2, 6, 10), (3, 7, 11), (4, 8, 12)]
```

This will give you elements at `0,k,2k..` / `1,k+1,2k+1..` / `2,k+2,2k+2..` where `k=len(n)/x`. So you get `k` sublists of length `x`.

**Note:** This will only work if `len(n)=k*x` perfectly. If not the results would be as below...

```
>>> k=5
>>> zip(*[n[i:i+k] for i in range(0,len(n),k)])
[(1, 6, 11), (2, 7, 12)]
```

Comment: @thenewb did this help? Do you've any more questions?